# Can not access quorum's contract from webpage *CORS*

Tags: web3js, blockchain, quorum, cors

I am getting following error on browser's console while accessing contracts.

> Failed to load http://localhost:22000/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

How can I fix it?

Following is code:

```
    var output = web3.eth.coinbase;
    $('#candidateName').text(output);
```